# SlidingTabLayout current item set is not shown when activity is first loaded

Tags: android

I am using sliding tab layout with view pager.My sliding tab layout strips shows many items, numbers form 10 to 200.

Below Images describes my problem completely:first is how it works and second image shows the problem i am having.

1. First Image(How my Tabs works) : 
   [image: Below is the image showing how my Sliding Tab Layout works]
2. second Image (The problem i am having and what is to be achieved) :

[image: Below is the image showing my problem and what exactly i wanted:]

My SlidingTabLayoutClass:

```
public class SlidingTabLayout extends HorizontalScrollView {

/**
 * Allows complete control over the colors drawn in the tab layout. Set with
 * {@link #setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer)}.
 */
public interface TabColorizer {

    /**
     * @return return the color of the indicator used when {@code position} is selected.
     */
    int getIndicatorColor(int position);

    /**
     * @return return the color of the divider drawn to the right of {@code position}.
     */
    int getDividerColor(int position);

}

private static final int TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS = 24;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS = 16;
private static final int TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP = 12;

private int mTitleOffset;

private int mTabViewLayoutId;
private int mTabViewTextViewId;

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mViewPagerPageChangeListener;

private final SlidingTabStrip mTabStrip;

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SlidingTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    // Disable the Scroll Bar
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    // Make sure that the Tab Strips fills this View
    setFillViewport(true);

    mTitleOffset = (int) (TITLE_OFFSET_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    mTabStrip = new SlidingTabStrip(context);
    addView(mTabStrip, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}

/**
 * Set the custom {@link TabColorizer} to be used.
 *
 * If you only require simple custmisation then you can use
 * {@link #setSelectedIndicatorColors(int...)} and {@link #setDividerColors(int...)} to achieve
 * similar effects.
 */
public void setCustomTabColorizer(TabColorizer tabColorizer) {
    mTabStrip.setCustomTabColorizer(tabColorizer);
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for indicating the selected tab. These colors are treated as a
 * circular array. Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setSelectedIndicatorColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Sets the colors to be used for tab dividers. These colors are treated as a circular array.
 * Providing one color will mean that all tabs are indicated with the same color.
 */
public void setDividerColors(int... colors) {
    mTabStrip.setDividerColors(colors);
}

/**
 * Set the {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener}. When using {@link SlidingTabLayout} you are
 * required to set any {@link ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener} through this method. This is so
 * that the layout can update it's scroll position correctly.
 *
 * @see ViewPager#setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener)
 */
public void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    mViewPagerPageChangeListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Set the custom layout to be inflated for the tab views.
 *
 * @param layoutResId Layout id to be inflated
 * @param textViewId id of the {@link TextView} in the inflated view
 */
public void setCustomTabView(int layoutResId, int textViewId) {
    mTabViewLayoutId = layoutResId;
    mTabViewTextViewId = textViewId;
}

/**
 * Sets the associated view pager. Note that the assumption here is that the pager content
 * (number of tabs and tab titles) does not change after this call has been made.
 */
public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    mTabStrip.removeAllViews();

    mViewPager = viewPager;
    if (viewPager != null) {
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new InternalViewPagerListener());
        populateTabStrip();
    }
}

/**
 * Create a default view to be used for tabs. This is called if a custom tab view is not set via
 * {@link #setCustomTabView(int, int)}.
 */
protected TextView createDefaultTabView(Context context) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, TAB_VIEW_TEXT_SIZE_SP);
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // If we're running on Honeycomb or newer, then we can use the Theme's
        // selectableItemBackground to ensure that the View has a pressed state
        TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
        getContext().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground,
                outValue, true);
        textView.setBackgroundResource(outValue.resourceId);
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        // If we're running on ICS or newer, enable all-caps to match the Action Bar tab style
        textView.setAllCaps(true);
    }

    int padding = (int) (TAB_VIEW_PADDING_DIPS * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    textView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);

    return textView;
}

private void populateTabStrip() {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    final View.OnClickListener tabClickListener = new TabClickListener();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View tabView = null;
        TextView tabTitleView = null;

        if (mTabViewLayoutId != 0) {
            // If there is a custom tab view layout id set, try and inflate it
            tabView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(mTabViewLayoutId, mTabStrip,
                    false);
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView.findViewById(mTabViewTextViewId);
        }

        if (tabView == null) {
            tabView = createDefaultTabView(getContext());
        }

        if (tabTitleView == null && TextView.class.isInstance(tabView)) {
            tabTitleView = (TextView) tabView;
        }

        tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));
        tabView.setOnClickListener(tabClickListener);

        mTabStrip.addView(tabView);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    if (mViewPager != null) {
        scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0);
    }
}

private void scrollToTab(int tabIndex, int positionOffset) {
    final int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
    if (tabStripChildCount == 0 || tabIndex < 0 || tabIndex >= tabStripChildCount) {
        return;
    }

    View selectedChild = mTabStrip.getChildAt(tabIndex);
    if (selectedChild != null) {
        int targetScrollX = selectedChild.getLeft() + positionOffset;

        if (tabIndex > 0 || positionOffset > 0) {
            // If we're not at the first child and are mid-scroll, make sure we obey the offset
            targetScrollX -= mTitleOffset;
        }

        scrollTo(targetScrollX, 0);
    }
}

private class InternalViewPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private int mScrollState;

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        int tabStripChildCount = mTabStrip.getChildCount();
        if ((tabStripChildCount == 0) || (position < 0) || (position >= tabStripChildCount)) {
            return;
        }

        mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, positionOffset);

        View selectedTitle = mTabStrip.getChildAt(position);
        int extraOffset = (selectedTitle != null)
                ? (int) (positionOffset * selectedTitle.getWidth())
                : 0;
        scrollToTab(position, extraOffset);

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset,
                    positionOffsetPixels);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mScrollState = state;

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        if (mScrollState == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            mTabStrip.onViewPagerPageChanged(position, 0f);
            scrollToTab(position, 0);
        }

        if (mViewPagerPageChangeListener != null) {
            mViewPagerPageChangeListener.onPageSelected(position);
        }
    }

}

private class TabClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mTabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {
            if (v == mTabStrip.getChildAt(i)) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
                return;
              }
          }
      }
  }

}
```

Please help solving my problem

Ways I have tried:

1.)I tried calling scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0); in setViewPager method of SlidingTabLayout class,but it doesnt work to show the 6 item when activity is first loaded.

2.)In place of scrollToTab(mViewPager.getCurrentItem(), 0); in setViewPager method of SlidingTabLayout class,i tried calling scrollTo(500,0),it shows me the scrolled sliding tab strip when activity is first loaded,this way is not efficient as we don't know exactly what value is to be put instead of 500 for different devices.

This Sliding Tab layout which i have created is similar to one shown below,only difference is my tabs shows numbers with circular backgroud,and below image depicts only three tabs and my tab layout contains many tabs numbered from 10 to 200.
[image]

Comment: i get that you are trying to create tabs, but am i right to say.. that 10,20, 30 numbers are tabs you created?

Comment: yes you are right,10,20 30...are the tabs of my sliding tab layout.Check populateTabStrip() method from which the text is getting set in those tabs from this line: tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));

Comment: so whenever you open the activity, you wanted your focus on tab number 6?

Comment: yes..check the second image,which shows exactly what i want when activity is loaded for the first time

Comment: See,what happening as of now,as shown in second image:as in activity before setting adapter of view pager i am doing setCurrentItem(6),so whats happening is when activity is loaded for the first time:1.) In my sliding tab layout 60 is getting highlighted in Orange color,but the thing is its not shown,currently visible items are 10,20,30,40,50 ,so when i will swipe then 60 will be shown highlighted in orange and nd i want 60 along with its near by items should be shown by default when activity is first loaded as i have done set current item to 6.did u understand now?

Comment: yup i got what you mean!

Comment: so what is to be done to achieve it??

Comment: You have viewPager instance in your mainActivity right?

Comment: yes,I have with that only in my MainActivity I am setting the current item:see second image like this:viewPager.setCurrentItem(6)

Comment: i have tried to read documentation, and posted tried this, in my case, it does work, but i have just two tabs, let me know it works for you or not!

Comment: It will not work for your case if you add more tabs,trying adding 10 more items ans set the current item as 6,and if check on some phone which is quiet small to show all 10 items at once,then you will see that when your activity is first loaded that 6th item will be highlighted, but it will appear to you only when you swipe.

Comment: For me also what you said will work if i set my current item to 2,so when my activity is first loaded i will be able to see it.

Comment: alright, will post an answer, if i find something.. effective solution.. it made me hungry!!

Comment: Is this thing not at all possible? as no answers came..

Comment: i have been busy with my other projects, haven't actually tried to look for it... but i have been meaning to ask you.. why you want to do that thing? why don't u just put the screen that you want to show to user first, put in first fragment(tab)?

Comment: I want that only because of some project requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Gallery is a View commonly used to display items in a horizontally scrolling list that locks the current selection at the center.**

1. Gallery can be used to show Views in a horizontal list, and user can
   select a View , User selected view will be shown in center of the
   Horizontal list
2. The items of Gallery are populated from an Adapter, similar to
   ListView, in which ListView items are populated from an Adapter.
3. We need to create an Adapter class which extends BaseAdapter class
   and override  getView() method.
4. getView() method called automatically for all items of Gallery
   (similar to list view in which getView() method called for each item
   of ListView)

**GalleryView Example:**
In our GalleryView Example we have populated the Gallery with images.
The images will be shown in horizontal list, when user selects/click on an image , the selected Image will be shown in center of the screen. (See the Screenshot below)

**Handle touch/click event on Gallery:**
We need to add click Listener to gallery  in order to handle the touch event on gallery.
[image]

**main.xml**

We have a gallery and an ImageView, we will show the User selected image in ImageView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {

         ImageView selectedImage;  
         private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                    R.drawable.image1,
                    R.drawable.image2,
                    R.drawable.image3,
                    R.drawable.image4,
                    R.drawable.image5,
                    R.drawable.image6,
                    R.drawable.image7,
                    R.drawable.image8
            };
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

                 Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
            selectedImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            gallery.setSpacing(1);
            gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryImageAdapter(this));

             // clicklistener for Gallery
            gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your selected position = " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // show the selected Image
                    selectedImage.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
                }
            });
        }

    }
**GalleryImageAdapter** 


    public class GalleryImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
    {
        private Context mContext;

        private Integer[] mImageIds = {
                R.drawable.image1,
                R.drawable.image2,
                R.drawable.image3,
                R.drawable.image4,
                R.drawable.image5,
                R.drawable.image6,
                R.drawable.image7,
                R.drawable.image8
        };

        public GalleryImageAdapter(Context context) 
        {
            mContext = context;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        // Override this method according to your need
        public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);

            i.setImageResource(mImageIds[index]);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(200, 200));

            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);

            return i;
        }
    }
```

Note:This example populates Images in Gallery,for the question which i posted above,I have populated my gallery with TextViews showing number from 10 to 200,and for giving orange color circle background when an item is selected,I have created a drawable of selector type like below:

**item_selector.xml**

```
<selector>
        <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="your orange color circle drawable"></item>
</selector>
```

and set this selector as a background of TextView(item of Gallery)

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved aforementioned problem by using Gallery Control of android instead of SlidingTabLayout with View Pager,with gallery I am able to show the 6 item as selected default and its visible also when activity is loaded for the first time.
Code:
mGallery.setSelection(6);

Comment: upvoted! happy that you got solution. can you just tell me what Gallay is? information about it? just want to know.

Comment: Sure!!Please look at example below:

Comment: i get that code.. but what gallary is? is it a new way to build tabs?

Comment: I have posted sample along with description about what gallery is and how it works..please check below

Comment: i upvoted this already. . its the same... n u should've updated this question. . its duplication :p

Answer (score 0):

//try this code , it works for me .

```
 ViewPager.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() 
 {

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() 
    {

    ViewPager.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

    mPager.setCurrentItem(tabSelectedPosition, true);
    }
});
```